# Why can't I change the font-family on my navbar?

Tags: html, css

I can't find the appropriate selector to use in order to change the font type for my main menu items; not the drop down list.

I deleted all the css font types in case something was overriding things and that resulted in nothing. I then inserted into each line of my css file 'font-family:cursive' for each selector and none of those worked to change the font. I"ve also noticed that my text decorations won't work for the menu items but I'm going to call that a lost at this point. Here are my work files:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

.Logo {
  padding: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background: url("http://photokaz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/New-Web-Belize-Dock-Final-2048.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

a {
  font-family: cursive;
}

h2 {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #646ecb;
  color: #f0f1f5;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30pt;
  letter-spacing: 15px;
}


/*background navbar color*/

.navbar {
  background: teal;
  height: 40px;
  width: 700px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-family: cursive;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #ffdc3d;
  text-decoration: underline !important;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li:hover ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: teal;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

nav ul ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/maintravel2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">



  <title>Round-a-Whirl</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div></div>
      <h2><img src="HatchfulExport-All/linkedin_banner_image_1.png" height=75 width="auto" class="Logo"></h2>
    </header>
    <div class="navbar">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plane"> Flights</i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-hotel"> Hotel</i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-car"> Car Rental</i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"> Discover</i></a>
            <ul>
              <li>Vacation</li>
              <li>Cruise</li>
              <li>City</li>
              <li>Nature</li>
              <li>Getaways</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tag"> Deals</i></a></li>

        </ul>

      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <article>
    This is a simple site I created using HTML and CSS of a travel site for the fictional Round-a-Whirl travel company.
  </article>


  <footer>
    Round-a-Whirl &copy; 2019
  </footer>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text is inside the `<i>` tag and the font-family is being overridden by Font Awesome. Try this instead:

`<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plane"></i> Flights</a></li>`

Comment: Thanks this was the perfect answer. This fixed my text-decoration issue as well!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to increase specificity. 
Try:

```
.navbar nav ul {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting your text inside `<i>` tag which is applying font-awesome's style. Instead do this.

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plane"></i>Flights</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You use .fa in the wrong way, the font-family is rewrited for icon :

```
.fa, .far, .fas {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
}
```

You have to had your text after : `<i class="fa fa-plane"></i>` not in.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

.Logo {
  padding: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background: url("http://photokaz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/New-Web-Belize-Dock-Final-2048.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

a {
  font-family: cursive;
}

h2 {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #646ecb;
  color: #f0f1f5;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30pt;
  letter-spacing: 15px;
}


/*background navbar color*/

.navbar {
  background: teal;
  height: 40px;
  width: 700px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-family: cursive;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #ffdc3d;
  text-decoration: underline !important;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li:hover ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: teal;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

nav ul ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/maintravel2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">



  <title>Round-a-Whirl</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div></div>
      <h2><img src="HatchfulExport-All/linkedin_banner_image_1.png" height=75 width="auto" class="Logo"></h2>
    </header>
    <div class="navbar">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plane"> </i>  Flights</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-hotel"> </i> Hotel</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-car"> </i> Car Rental</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"> </i> Discover</a>
            <ul>
              <li>Vacation</li>
              <li>Cruise</li>
              <li>City</li>
              <li>Nature</li>
              <li>Getaways</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> Deals</a></li>

        </ul>

      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <article>
    This is a simple site I created using HTML and CSS of a travel site for the fictional Round-a-Whirl travel company.
  </article>


  <footer>
    Round-a-Whirl &copy; 2019
  </footer>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```